# Determine encoding of sharepoint web service soap response

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, soap

I am sending a soap XMLHTTP request to a sharepoint web service.
The response is wrapped in the soap xml as usual.
The problem is that some "ows_###" row attributes are further encoded in HTML and some are not.

Example:

```
<z:row
ows_Title='Example'
ows_Who='Adam &amp; Bill'
ows_Content='&lt;div&gt;This &amp;amp; this is HTML.&lt;/div&gt;'
ows_ID='1' />
```

Decoding the xml, the values are:

```
ows_Title = 'Example'
ows_Who = 'Adam & Bill'
ows_Content= '<div>This &amp; this is HTML.</div>'
```

ows_Content is now HTML so I parse it to get the raw text:

```
'This & this is HTML.'
```

If I try to parse ows_Who as HTML I get an error due to the ampersand starting an escape sequence.

I can parse the HTML fine so long as I know it is HTML.

- How can I determine the encoding of each attribute?
- How can I force all attributes to be HTML encoded?

Comment: Are you sure the error is because of the ampersand? Please share the error  message you get. Note that &amp; is the escape sequence in HTML for ampersand. You should be able to HTMLDecode it just fine.

Comment: The error is an invalid entity reference. That is due to the &. I have edited the question to clarify the problem. I don't know which attributes are returning HTML and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GetList web service to get the details of a list. RichText is one of the attributes of a field of the list.